# Include a comma separator for data labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a box plot using `ggplot` which lists the data labels, but am not able to bring a comma separator for 1000s in the data label. `sep =","` in `aes` doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
ggplot(based,aes(x=Cust=Claim.USD)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data=subset(based,USD>10000), aes(label=USD, sep=","),
            hjust=1, vjust=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `comma` function is in the `scales` package, which you'll need to load. Also get rid of `sep`, that's not an aesthetic mapping. This should work:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(based,aes(x=Cust=Claim.USD)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data=subset(based,USD>10000), aes(label = comma(USD)),
            hjust=1, vjust=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

Judging by your argument names, you might prefer `scales::dollar` instead of `scales::comma`.