# How to change the format on data labels with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the format of the numbers in data labels (to comma) on the ggplot, but can not find the answer. Hop you can help :)

Here is the example:

```
library("scales")
library("tidyverse")
df = tibble(year = as.factor(c(2016,2016,2017,2017)),
        kpi = c("value", "volume","value", "volume"),
        values = c(99999,8888,111111,11000)) 
df %>%
ggplot()+
aes(year,values, fill = kpi) +
geom_col() +
scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
stat_summary(fun.y = sum,
           aes(label = ..y..,
               group = year),
           geom = "text",
           vjust = 1,
           size =3) +
labs(title = "KPI By Year",
     fill = "KPIs",
     y = NULL,x = "Year")+
theme(legend.position="bottom")+
facet_wrap(~kpi, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)
```

And this is what I get. Formatting with comma would help a lot with readability.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to add a thousands separator? (label = comma)

Comment: If so, may be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427639/include-a-comma-separator-for-data-labels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the format function in your label statement with argument 'big.mark = ",":

```
df %>%
  ggplot()+
  aes(year,values, fill = kpi) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum,
               aes(label = format(..y.., big.mark = ","),
                   group = year),
               geom = "text",
               vjust = 1,
               size =3) +
  labs(title = "KPI By Year",
       fill = "KPIs",
       y = NULL,x = "Year")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  facet_wrap(~kpi, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just change `label = ..y..` to `label = format(as.numeric(..y..), nsmall=0, big.mark=",")`

```
library("scales")
library("tidyverse")
df = tibble(year = as.factor(c(2016,2016,2017,2017)),
            kpi = c("value", "volume","value", "volume"),
            values = c(99999,8888,111111,11000)) 
df %>%
  ggplot()+
  aes(year,values, fill = kpi) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +

  stat_summary(fun.y = sum,
               aes(label = format(as.numeric(..y..), nsmall=0, big.mark=","),
                   group = year),
               geom = "text",
               vjust = 1,
               size =3) +


  labs(title = "KPI By Year",
       fill = "KPIs",
       y = NULL,x = "Year")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  facet_wrap(~kpi, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu6Zt.png)

Based on: [Format number in R with both comma thousands separator and specified decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals)